# How do I load Google Maps API globally before Jest runs any tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-maps, jestjs, google-maps-api-2

Moving to NX, I have migrated my library [`@bespunky/angular-google-maps`](https://github.com/BeSpunky/angular-google-maps) from karma + jasmine to jest and my tests are failing.

Many of the tests use native objects (e.g. `google.maps.Map` or `google.maps.Marker`). There are existing mock libraries for google maps but they don't cover even 30% of all the Google Maps API.

I intend to implement at least 80% of the native API in my Angular library at some point, which is why neither a mock library nor implementing mocks for every native item I use are viable options as the mocks will quickly become unmaintainable.

For that reason I have chosen to manually download the API file and plant it in my codebase, then simply run it when the test environment initializes. Instead of mocking the entire library, I mock the relevant functions on real objects each time. This worked correctly on karma but fails on jest.

I tried adding the file under `setupFiles`, `setupFilesAfterEnv`, `globalSetup` in my `jest.config.js`. All alternatives execute the file, but when executed, the following error is thrown:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined`

It's like the `google` namespace doesn't get loaded. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that jest doesn't run on browser and karma did.

I even tried to tell jest to work with DOM simulation, adding the following in my `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testEnvironmentOptions: { html: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` }
};
```

Same result.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [@googlemaps/jest-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/jest-mocks) which is a partially mocked API for Google Maps JS.

**This library is open to pull requests and is easy to patch.**

```js
import { initialize } from "@googlemaps/jest-mocks";

beforeEach(() => {
  initialize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Justin, I have considered your library a few times before posting my question. Unfortunately it is not suffice for my needs as it only covers a small part of Google Maps API. It would mean I either have to wait for you to develop more features, or help maintain the library - both of which are not viable for me.

Comment: I would probably move everything to selenium based testing in that case. It's going to be slow and fragile but it will use the API as expected. I have some libraries doing this within GitHub actions now. https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/blob/main/e2e/selenium.test.ts https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/blob/main/.github/workflows/e2e.yml

Comment: or https://playwright.dev/